# where query count result > 0

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

I need to do a query like this:

```
SELECT wposts.ID FROM posts wposts WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM surveys WHERE POST_ID = wposts.ID) > 0
```

but need it to be working ?

Comment: sorry, the query above do not work

Comment: Wiika, we need more information than that in order to help you. What about it doesn't work? Does it throw an error? Does it return the wrong results? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select returns by default a "set", which is not compatible with an integer.
You can do something like:

> SELECT wposts.ID FROM posts wposts WHERE  0 NOT IN ( SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM surveys WHERE POST_ID = wposts.ID)

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL works fast, if the foreign key `surveys.POST_ID` is indexed.

```
SELECT wposts.ID FROM posts wposts
    INNER JOIN surveys ON surveys.POST_ID = wposts.ID
GROUP BY wposts.ID
```